# Liquibase: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, liquibase

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a diff for two postgres databases:

*Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver*

I'm running this on Windows.  Most of the solutions I've seen are for Maven, which I'm not running as far as I know.

Can anyone tell me if there is a workaroud?

The following is my command:

```
liquibase --outputFile=mydiff.txt diff
```

Comment: I would start with the documentation:https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/installation/using-the-lb-installer.html. And:https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/postgresql.html?Highlight=postgresql

Comment: I checked the docs.  It says "To test your connection, try running Liquibase with the JDBC driver located in the same directory as Liquibase".   Where do I find the driver?

Comment: You will need to download it  from here:https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html per the tutorial link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your liquibase.properties file has a value for classpath:,
ex.

```
classpath: ../drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar
```

The value is just an example, you need to point it to wherever your jdbc driver to access your postgresql db lives.